# Replacing string with tuple in list of tuples

Tags: python, list, replace, tuples

I am very sorry to be asking this kind of newbie question but here it goes. So I basically have this returned as levels:

```
levels = [(1, 210, 30, 500, 500, 'white'),(1, 210, 30, 200, 400, 'white'),(1, 210, 30, 600, 300, 'white')]
```

And I want to iterate through it and replace 'white' with white which is simply (255,255,255). Python complained about tuples not being changeable, so I would need to create a new list with the tuples instead of white. Is there a quick way to do this?

Comment: Do you want `1, 210, 30, 500, 500, '255,255,255`' or `1, 210, 30, 500, 500, (255,255,255)`, or `1, 210, 30, 500, 500, 255, 255, 255` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do

```
levelsList = [list(x) for x in level]
```

After that you can change the 'white' string

Comment: you're welcome. If you want to replace the white in also one line, you could do it via 
`levelsList2 = [[(255,255,255) if l=='white' else l for l in level] for level in levelsList]`
but it  does not really enhance the readabillity

Comment: for some reason this worked for days and now it doesn't. I'm at a loss.

Comment: strange did you change something in the level list?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep it as a list of tuples, you can try:

```
replacements = {"white": (255, 255, 255)}
levelsList = [(a, b, c, d, e, replacements.get(f, f)) for a, b, c, d, e, f in levels]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a great way to do it too :)